# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm getting an error on casting. I don't know how to fix it

- springMVC collections
- hibrnate 4.3.5

Exception :

```
    type Rapport d''exception

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:39)
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:64)
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
```

and my UserDao.java

```
public boolean checkLogin(User user) {
    String hql = "FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username and u.password = :password";
    Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("username", user.getClass());
    query.setParameter("password", user.getPassword());
    int result;
    query.setMaxResults(1);
    result = query.list().size();

    if(result < 1) {
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your entité code PLEASE ?

Comment: My table user :
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

Comment: Please add additional details to the original question by using the edit feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query.setParameter("username", user.getClass());` may be the cause of the problem.

Try following:

```
query.setParameter("username", user.getUsername());
```

I am assuming your User class has getUsername() method.